# xml serialization - adding name space to element that is not root

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsi

I am working in C#, I'm trying to do xml serialization I get `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` on the root element, I need that also on another element.

The reason that I need it, is because I get the xml as a string and I need to do xml serialization only on the `<Header>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Movie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
....
  </Header
  <Title>Starship Troopers</Title>
  <Rating>6.9</Rating>
  <ReleaseDate>1997-11-07T00:00:00</ReleaseDate>
</Movie>
```

Comment: How do you create your xml? Via attributes?